# ODATA Connected Service Advanced Settings "GenerateMultipleFiles" option is missing

Tags: odata

The generate multiple files option is not available in the 0.13.0 Settings UI but there is an entry in the ConnectedService.json settings file.

I tried editing the settings file manually and forcing an update but it did not work.

Has this feature been deprecated or is it just broken? I also noticed the custom namespace option did not seem to work either.

This is what shows up in the online documents:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/connectedservice/generating-multiple-files
[image: generate-multiple-files-setting]
Another doc shows a different UI...
[image: Code Generation Tool]

What my VS 2017/2019 extension shows:
[image: Code Generation Tool V0.13.0]

The latest version seems to be version 0.13, the feature seems to be introduced in the OData Connected Service 0.9.1 Release.

Answer (score 0):

The "Generate Multiple Files" option is only available when you're targeting an OData v4 service. This also applies to a few other settings as well. Confirm whether you're targeting an OData v1, v2 or v3 service, if that's the case, that would explain why you're seeing different available options. The docs should be updated to reflect this.